# FOSElasticaBundle & Propel

Tags: symfony, foselasticabundle

I have installed FOSElasticaBundle "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "^3.2"
(with symfony 2.8.8) and tried to define this simple configuration

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { host: %elastic_host%, port: %elastic_port% }
    indexes:
        project:
            types:
                item:
                    mappings:
                        id: { type: integer }
                        itemno: { type: string }
                    persistence:
                        driver: propel
                        model: Model\Item\Item
                        provider: ~
```

Unfortunately I'm getting following error

> The parent definition "fos_elastica.listener.prototype.propel" defined
>   for definition "fos_elastica.listener.project.item" does not
>   exist.

As I read through the documentation, there is no "listener" available for propel - that's why I'm a little bit confused about the error message. I already tried to define the missing definition, but with no result.

Is it necessary to define any class/service as provider for the type? In the documentation I couldn't find anything about that?

Thanks.